# TLS echo server and echoclient in python crashes

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, client-server

I wrote a simple echo server client code in Python. I also generated keyfile.pem and certfile.pem, with commands:

`openssl genrsa -des3 -out keyfile.pem 2048` and

`openssl req -new -key keyfile.pem -out certfile.pem`

when I ran client server, it asked me about passphase: `Enter PEM pass phrase:` and I enterec correct text and got errors (dont really know why):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "echo_server.py", line 19, in <module>
    connection, client_address= tls_server.accept()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 354, in accept
    suppress_ragged_eofs=self.suppress_ragged_eofs),   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 141, in __init__
    ciphers) ssl.SSLError: [Errno 336445449] _ssl.c:365: error:140DC009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib
```

Heres my server.py:

```
#server side
# echo client
from socket import *
from ssl import *

#create socket
server_socket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

#Bind to an unused port on the local machine
server_socket.bind(('localhost',6668))

#listen for connection
server_socket.listen (1)
tls_server = wrap_socket(server_socket, ssl_version=PROTOCOL_TLSv1, cert_reqs=CERT_NONE, server_side=True, keyfile='./keyfile.pem', certfile='./certfile.pem')

print('server started')

#accept connection
connection, client_address= tls_server.accept()
print ('connection from', client_address)

#server is not finnished
finnished =False

#while not finnished
while not finnished:


    #send and receive data from the client socket
    data_in=connection.recv(1024)
    message=data_in.decode()
    print('client send',message)

    if message=='quit':
        finnished= True
    else:

        data_out=message.encode()
        connection.send(data_out)

#close the connection
connection.shutdown(SHUT_RDWR)
connection.close()

#close the server socket
server_socket.shutdown(SHUT_RDWR)
server_socket.close()
```

and client.py:

```
#client side
# echo client
from socket import *
from ssl import *

#user is not finnished
finnished =False

#create socket
client_socket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tls_client = wrap_socket(client_socket, ssl_version=PROTOCOL_TLSv1, cert_reqs=CERT_NONE)


#connect to the echo server
tls_client.connect(('localhost',6668))

#while not finnished
while not finnished:

    #message
    message=input ('enter message:   ')

    data_out= message.encode ()

    #send data out
    tls_client.send(data_out)    

    #receive data
    data_in=tls_client.recv(1024)


    #decode message
    response= data_in.decode()
    print('Received from client:', response)

    reapet=input('yes or no?  ')


    if reapet == 'n':
        finnished= True
        client_socket.send(b'quit')



#close the socket
client_socket.shutdown(SHUT_RDWR)
client_socket.close()
```

What might be wrong? I use Kubuntu 12.04 LTS and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout my.key -out my.crt
```

Comment: Geez @Mimi, works now! Could you please explain, what was wrong with my cert and key file? Thanks:)